# Plotting multiple contour plots

Tags: plotting

Suppose, I have a table with five columns where first four columns represent some variable parameters and fifth column represents value of function at those parameters. I want to have a contour plot for every possible combination of these four parameters. For example- First Using first and second column then first and third and so on. One way to do this is to plot every possible combination of these parameters and write  `ListContourPlot` command for every combination. Is there any minimal way to plot contours for every possible combination? I have tried-

```
For[i = 1, i <= 10, i++,
d1 = RandomReal[{100, 1000}];
d2 = RandomReal[{100, 1000}];
d3 = RandomReal[{100, 1000}];
d4 = RandomReal[{100, 1000}];
d5 = d1 + d2 + d3 + d4 ;
list[i] = {d1, d2, d3, d4, d5};
]
list1 = Table[list[i], {i, 1, 10}];
list2 = list1[[All, {1, 2, 5}]];
list3 = list1[[All, {1, 3, 5}]];
list4 = list1[[All, {1, 4, 5}]];
ListContourPlot[list2]
ListContourPlot[list3]
ListContourPlot[list4]
```

Comment: Can you present a minimal example? What have you tried?

Comment: @MauricioLobos I have edited the question.

Comment: Try this: `Table[ListContourPlot[list[[All, Append[xy, 5]]]], {xy, Subsets[Range[4], {2}]}]`

Comment: @J.M. How can I give specific frame labels for each plot?

Comment: Look up `PlotLabel`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to get all possible pairs of contour plots.

First, generate data (avoiding the notorious `For` function):

```
n = 100;  (* Number of samples *)
k = 4; (* Number of predictor variables *)
(* Generate data *)
data = RandomReal[{100, 1000}, {n, k + 1}];
(* (k+1)-th variable as a function of the first k variables *)
data[[All, k + 1]] = Sum[data[[All, i]], {i, k}];
```

Now produce all possible pairwise plots:

```
pairs = Select[Tuples[Range[1, k], 2], #[[1]] < #[[2]] &];
Table[ListContourPlot[data[[All, Flatten[{pairs[[i]], k + 1}]]]], {i, Length[pairs]}]
```

[image: All possible pairwise plots]

Comment: Consider using `Subsets[]` instead of `Tuples[]`.

Comment: Thanks @J.M.  (This is one of the reasons I attempt to answer these questions.  You folks help me (and everybody else) learn to be more efficient and expose us to the zillions of commands I don't know.)

Answer (score 1):

```
SeedRandom[1]
For[i = 1, i <= 10, i++,
 d1 = RandomReal[{100, 1000}];
 d2 = RandomReal[{100, 1000}];
 d3 = RandomReal[{100, 1000}];
 d4 = RandomReal[{100, 1000}];
 d5 = d1 + d2 + d3 + d4;
 list[i] = {d1, d2, d3, d4, d5};]
list1 = Table[list[i], {i, 1, 10}];
```

**Note** that this can be coded more simply as

```
SeedRandom[1]
list2 = Flatten[{#, Total[#]}] & /@
   RandomReal[{100, 1000}, {10, 4}];
```

Verifying the equivalence,

```
list1 === list2

(*  True  *)
```

**EDIT** Added labels

```
labels = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "Total"};

(ListContourPlot[
      list1[[All, {#[[1]], #[[2]], 5}]],
      FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@labels[[#]]),
      PlotLabel -> Style["ContourPlot of " <> Last[labels], 14, Bold]] & /@
    Subsets[Range[4], {2}]) //
  Partition[#, 2] & //
 Grid[#, Spacings -> {2, 2}] &
```

[image]

Comment: How can I give specific frame labels to each plot?

Comment: Total no. of plots should be six?

Comment: @solphy - I merely produced what was shown in your code.

Comment: Is it possible to label elements of the list and use those labels as `FrameLabel` for each individual plot?

Comment: @solphy - spend some time formulating your questions so that they are completely described and do not need repeated modifications.